# Is there a word - not 'anachronistic' - that means 'impossibly futuristic for the historical period'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word - not 'anachronistic' - that means 'impossibly futuristic for the historical period'?

Like a movie made in the 2010s, set in the 1920s where someone is driving a 1950s car.

Comment: The title asks for a word but the tag is about idiom, which are you after?

Comment: Oh, a movie with mistakes: not true to the period.

Comment: It is a word-request but that tag is too much hard work for me.

Answer (score 3):

[***Prochronistic:***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prochronistic) characterized by ***prochronism,*** which is

> an anachronism marked by the assignment of something (as an event) to a date earlier than the actual historical one [(*Merriam-Webster*)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prochronism)
>
> an impossible anachronism which occurs when an object or idea has not yet been invented when the situation takes place, and therefore could not have possibly existed at the time [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism#Prochronism)

Comment: Thanks, that's the word.